# rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = RPC method not implemented

Tags: go, grpc-go

I have been trying to create a grpc client in Go and I have followed the correct instructions as shown in the official [grpc](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/go/#client) site. When I start my grpc server written in node.js, the connection works well but upon compiling the protocol buffer in Go and creating a client interface with the correct grpc client configurations, I run into an error.

Here is my what I have in my `identity.pb.go`.

```
type IdentityServiceClient interface {
    CreateUser(ctx context.Context, in *GoogleIdToken, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (error, *UserInfo)
}

type simpleServerClient struct {
    connection *grpc.ClientConn
}

func NewSimpleServerClient(connection *grpc.ClientConn) IdentityServiceClient {
    return &simpleServerClient{connection}
}

func (simpleClient *simpleServerClient) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, in *GoogleIdToken, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (error, *UserInfo) {
    out := new(UserInfo)
    err := simpleClient.connection.Invoke(ctx, "/protobuf.IdentityService/CreateUser", in, out, opts...)

    if err != nil {
        return err, nil
    }

    return nil, out
}
```

here is the `identity.proto`

```
syntax="proto3";

package protobuf;

service IdentityService {
    rpc CreateUser (GoogleIdToken) returns (UserInfo) {}
}

message GoogleIdToken {
    string token = 1;
}

message UserInfo {
    string name = 1;
    string email = 2;
    message Profile {
        string imageUrl = 1;
        string lastUpdated = 2;
    };
    Profile profile = 3;
    string token = 4;
}
```

here is my `main.go`

```
import pb "github.com/Duncanian/iam-gateway/server/protobuf"

func grpcConnection() {
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to start gRPC connection: %v", err)
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    client := pb.NewSimpleServerClient(conn)

    err, _ = client.CreateUser(context.Background(), &pb.GoogleIdToken{Token: "tevgvybububvvg"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create user: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println("Created user!")
}
```

I expect the output of passing a correct google auth token to get me the correct user details which are

```
name: user,
email: user.email@user.com,
profile: {
   imageUrl: myimageUrl,
   lastUpdated: mylastUpdatedTime,
},
token,
```

but got

```
rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = RPC method not implemented /protobuf.IdentityService/CreateUser
```

Here are my github repos:
[Go grpc client](https://github.com/Duncanian/iam-gateway/tree/ft-grpc-create-user-165677707) &
[Node JS grpc server](https://github.com/Duncanian/identity-management/blob/develop/server/procedures/createUser.ts)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Here is my solution:
After compiling `.proto` I created 2 files: `client.go` and `server.go`.

In `client.go` I implemented my methods (rpc in terms of protobuffers) and had a `main` function.

In `server.go` I defined a server struct `server` with one field: `Unimplemented*ServiceName*Server`. After that I also implemented the mentioned above methods, but those had a receiver type: `func (s *server) Foo(ctx context.Context, *other params*)`

That worked for me, hopefully it will help you!

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the `/protobuf.IdentityService/CreateUser` method is not registered at the server side. And I didn't see any service registration code in your linked server code. Please take a look at the node.js guide [here](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/node/).

Comment: I have registered the service [here](https://github.com/Duncanian/identity-management/blob/b35d825e0cdca706cd23ed8727c8b73ef48cd61e/server/index.ts#L50) in my node.js server. Also have a look at the procedures [here](https://github.com/Duncanian/identity-management/tree/develop/server/procedures).

Comment: I am not very familiar with how node.js works. I would suggest you to use a command line tool (like https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md) to check whether the service is indeed registered, because the error indicates it is not registered.

Answer (score 0):

Using GUI of grpc try to send your protos to your both servers and check for upcoming errors/correct endpoints.

In my case java proto had a package inside which was added to the endpoint.
Had `package com.example.grpc;`
instead of 
`option java_package = "com.example.grpc";`